# How can I create files from a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to create files (and put HTML in them) only using a `.htaccess` file (before you flame me with questions about *why on earth* I'd like to do that: it's just for fun, for a hack, not for any real production use).

Is that possible?

I think I could use the `mod_ext_filter` module with the `ExtFilterDefine` directive and then just call some standard UNIX commands (correct?), but is there some way that doesn't involve external commands, but standard directives instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, this is not possible.

Comment: Not even using ExtFilterDefine?

Comment: @PeterJaric No - that directive is only valid in the server context, not `.htaccess`.